# Multiple QMainWindow instances?

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

The `QMainWindow` is the main window in a Qt application. So usually you'd have only one, but would it be possible at all to have multiple `QMainWindow` instances in your application?

I am working on integrating a Qt-based GUI application *B* into another Qt-based GUI application *A*. Both these applications have a `QMainWindow`, and I was considering as a first step to create a new `QMainWindow` that has both old `QMainWindows` on tabs. That way it would allow me to concentrate on wiring the backend of GUI *B* to the backend of *A* without having to change anything in the user interface itself. Is this a viable approach, or do you have other suggestions?

Comment: I am in a pretty much similar situation, where I need 2 QMainWindows. In case you have gone this route, do you have an answer to the caveat pointed out by @caleb-huitt-cjhuitt, that is what happens to the menu bar on a Mac?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can have as many `QMainWindow` instances as you want. A `QMainWindow` is just a `QWidget` which provides a menu bar, toolbar, status bar and docking framework. But basically it is just a `QWidget` so you can have as many as you like.

Normally you only have a single `QMainWindow` for GUI design reasons since it can be confusing to have multiple main windows. However, when implementing applications like `QtAssistant` which can open a new instance of themselves then the one process has multiple main windows.

What you suggest should work. The window with the tabs would not need to be a `QMainWindow` unless you want to also want add a toolbar to that window as well.

Comment: The only caveat I would add is that the menus might get a little funky if you were to port to OS X.  They have some special handling to get the menus to work at the top of the screen, and I don't know how that would work with two main windows in one actual window.

Comment: Given that you can have multiple QMainWindow in application, could you use its docking framework inside a Mdi SubWindow? Would that be a good practice?

Comment: How this sub-QMainWindow(s) appears in main application window? How they are arranged: like MDI windows, overlap each other or need to place them in some container like tab widget or stacked widget, or they are stanalone - how? P.S. Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11860378/630169 and here https://forum.qt.io/topic/31841/qmainwindow-inside-a-widget-can-be-done-or-is-not-correct/7, need to use window->setWindowFlags(Qt::Widget);