# Promote QWidget to QMainWindow or add QMainWindow to QWidget from Qt Designer

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qmainwindow

**My problem:**

I want to customize the way the `title bar` works and looks for my application.

**My idea:**

I created a new `QWidget` form in `Qt Designer` and added a `QWidget` to it. I added the following code in constructor:

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

QGraphicsDropShadowEffect* effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
effect->setBlurRadius(20);
effect->setXOffset(0);
effect->setYOffset(0);
setGraphicsEffect(effect);
```

which makes the outer widget transparent and adds shadow to my inner widget. From this on I can create a custom title bar widget which I can implement however I want.

This is the result:

[image]

**My issue**

I want to make this usable from the designer as a main window and the `QWidget` doesn't allow me to add FROM THE DESIGNER `tool bars`, `menu bar` and `status bar`.

What I thought about was adding a QMainWindow widget as a child widget for the outer QWidget(which is transparent and acts as support for my shadow(the shadow is drawn on it)). I did this successfully but only from code:

```
QMainWindow *centralwidget = new QMainWindow();
centralwidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: lightgray;");
centralwidget->setGeometry(0, 0, 50, 20);
centralwidget->setWindowFlags(Qt::Widget);
this->layout()->addWidget(centralwidget);

QMenuBar *menuBar = new QMenuBar(centralwidget);
menuBar->addAction("Action");

QStatusBar *statusBar = new QStatusBar;
statusBar->showMessage("Status bar here");

centralwidget->addToolBar("tool bar");
centralwidget->setMenuBar(menuBar);
centralwidget->setStatusBar(statusBar);
```

This is the result:

[image]

**My question:**

How can I achieve this result from `Qt Designer`? Is it possible to promote a `QWidget` to `QMainWindow`? I cannot think to another way of doing it... It is really important for me to make it usable from `Qt Designer` because I intend to make it a template widget and be able to create e.g. a new `QCustomMainWindow` form `Qt Creator` just like you can create a `QWidget` or a `QMainWindow`.

Please help!

Comment: Start with a `QMainWindow`, and then apply the appropriate flags to it.  QMainWindow is a subclass of `QWidget`.  If it can't be done easily in the designer, it is pretty painless to do in code.  Do it in your constructor right after the `ui->setup()` call.

Comment: @phyatt Can you be more specific in the `apply the appropriate flags` part? As you can see, in order to have the shadow I need to paint the `QMainWindow` on top of a `QWidget` while still keeping the `Qt Designer` features in place. This is what I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another SO question similar to yours: [Qt4: Placing QMainWindow instance inside other QWidget/QMainWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344886/qt4-placing-qmainwindow-instance-inside-other-qwidget-qmainwindow)

Just adding on to my original comment:

Start with a `QMainWindow`, and then apply the appropriate flags to it. `QMainWindow` is a subclass of `QWidget`. If it can't be done easily in the designer, it is pretty painless to do in code. Do it in your constructor right after the `ui->setup()` call.

### Start with QMainWindow

[image: Project Selection Dialog]

[image: Form Selection Dialog]

### Customize Window Flags

So in the constructor in mainwindow.cpp, you put

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum

```
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Widget);
```

> This is the default type for QWidget. Widgets of this type are child
>   widgets if they have a parent, and independent windows if they have no
>   parent. See also Qt::Window and Qt::SubWindow.

```
// or if you want to apply more than one you, "or" it together, like so:
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::Tool);
```

Try out a couple of those and see what you like.

### Customize Widget Attributes

There are also Widget Attributes, that give you strong control over how your widgets look like and behave.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum

### Qt Style Sheets

In addition to all the flags and attributes above, you can also modify a ton of it with stylesheets:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

```
this->setStyleSheet("background: #000000;");
```

### Qt Designer Custom Widgets

And also if you are interested in making this a reusable thing in Qt Designer, you can make it into a Qt Designer plugin, or custom widgets.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html

### QMdiArea and QMdiWindow

Another path to look into besides using `QMainWindow` is `QMdiSubWindow`

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QMdiSubWindow.html